# 2nd monitor not working Ubuntu 20.04. not shown in display settings

Tags: multiple-monitors, display

I recently had to do a reinstall of Ubuntu 20.04 after a hard drive fail.
after many attempts previously I was able to get my 2nd monitor working, but unfortunately I didn't document the exact thing I did for it to work.

I'm now faced with the same problem. I can't get my second monitor working
I have spent all day googling the issue and following various suggestions like last time but to no avail, and it's really getting on my nerves.

My computer is new, my monitors are new, and the cables work.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check Settings > Screen Display, check the output of `dmesg`.  It could  also be wrong input setting on monitor.  Can you give more details than "not working"?  Can you switch monitors?

Answer (score -1):

I had a similiar problem, where there was only one possible resolution. Sadly during the last update my nvidia-driver completely broke. In my case I reinstalled my whole Ubuntu, but you should first try to find out, if it's a driver problem (even though those seem to be rare with Ubuntu)

I ran

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
```

and either you install the one you want by hand:

```
sudo apt install (your driver)
```

or you let the system install the recommended ones:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

If you installed any new drivers, do `reboot` afterwards!

I hope this helps a little bit!

Best wishes,

Lennart